# Adding html links to response of chatbot

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es

i am making a chatbot in node js and i am able to fetch the response
But the links are also shown as text. i want to display them as links

```
 responseText = `You want to learn about ${agent.parameters.course}. 
                  Here is a link to the course: ${coupon.link}`;
```

I need help converting the link text to html

i tried this ```

```
     responseText = `You want to learn about ${agent.parameters.course}. 
                    Here is a link to the course: ` + `<a href='${coupon.link}'>${coupon.link}</a>`;
```

```
but this is not working .Response i am getting from chatbot is


You want to learn about chatbots. Here is a link to the course: <a href='https://www.udemy.com/user/jana-bergant'>https://www.udemy.com/user/jana-bergant</a>

**Is there any way of parsing the string (use regular expression) and when you find a link in the string, add the html tag (<a href="...) around it.?
**
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Link method to convert you links from strings.
For Ex :

```js
 var str = "This is link";
var link = str.link("https://www.somelink.com");
var msg = "Hi "+link;
document.write(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
let course = 'https://www.google.com';
let coupon = 'https://www.stackoverflow.com';

const courseLink = `<a href='${course}'>${course}</a>`;
const couponLink = `<a href='${coupon}'>${coupon}</a>`;

responseText = `You want to learn about ${courseLink}. 
                  Here is a link to the course: ${couponLink}`;


document.body.innerHTML += responseText;
```

Answer (score 0):

On what integration (Facebook Messenger, Google Assistant) are you testing this? Messenger should make links clickable, but unfortunately Google Assistant doesn't allow this.

Comment: I am making my own bot interface in react js .

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your html lets say your div for messages is called
bot_msg so all you need to do is:

```
html = '<div class="bot_msg">' + '<a href= "#" onclick = "do_sth();return false;">click here to do sth</a>' + '</div>';
```

here I link to js fnc called do_sth in same html page. Then you append html string.